# How is the current Neo4j storage record composed?

Tags: neo4j

I'm interested in how the current Neo4j records in the store files are composed. I found this presentation explaining the composition for an older version : http://de.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals

But the record sizes in the current manual differ from the presentation:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.3/configuration-caches.html

Is there any source where you can look up theese kind of information?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you had a look at the source code by chance?

Comment: I tried to find the corresponding class by reading the JavaDoc API, but I didn't find any class implementing the reading process.